# .NET 8 : namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have upload code here in order to clear question.
https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/Bulky_MVC.git

I have add an entity `Customer` in the model project:

```
namespace BulkyBook.Models.Models
{
    //https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-core/
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in the web project, I try to add `CustomerController`:

```
namespace BulkyBook.Web.Areas.Customer.Controllers
{
    [Area("Customer")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public CustomerController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        // GET: CustomerController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Customer> objCustomerList = _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(objCustomerList);
            
        }
    }
}
```

And I get an error:

> CS0118 'Customer' is a namespace but is used like a type

I have tried to read many same question here and modify the namespace but the more I modify the more errors I got.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This error is for having a namespace that has a name the same as your model name.

So what is the namespace? is a Folder(directory) name.

You have a directory like this: `../Areas/Customer` and a model: `Customer`. So the compiler says you have a namespace `Customer` but you are trying to create an instance of it that is not valid for namespaces.

I think it's better to change your directory name to something else like: CustomerArea or Customers.

If you don't want to change the directory name, it is possible to explicitly reference your customer model like this:

```cs
List<BulkyBook.Models.Models.Customer> objCustomerList = _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAll().ToList();
```

Or you can add it as using:

```cs
using Customer = BulkyBook.Models.Models.Customer;

...

List<Customer> objCustomerList = _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAll().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help.
I have been change the folder to customers as you suggested. And then I have change the homecontroller and customercontroller in the project as you can see in the github.

Now I can't see the home page when the project is started instead of modification in the layout Page.
But I can navigate to /Customers/Customers
And The Layout Is ok.

Please take a look and help me. Thanks.